# NHibernate not saving entity

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I've got a project where I'm moving data from database to another.  I've got several tables working but the current one isn't.  When calling the `Session.Save(entity)` nothing appears to occur (no insert record being sent from NHibernate).  The entities that aren't saving are the `Configuration` ones in code below.  I'm included other code related to another entity which is working fine (about a dozen are).  Data is going from an Access database to a MSSQL database.

Code that copies object and performs the session save.  Nothing is inserted when save is called on `Configuration` entity.

```
public void Save(Entities.Access.CompTool o)
{
    var n = new CompTool();
    n.Name = o.Name;
    n.Description = o.Description;
    n.DefaultLocation = o.DefaultLocation;
    n.DateModified = o.DateModified;
    n.OldId = o.Id;

    GetSession().Save(n);
}

public void Save(Entities.Access.Configuration o)
{
    var n = new Configuration();
    n.Name = o.Name;
    n.Description = o.Description;
    n.Value = o.Value;

    GetSession().Save(n);
}
```

Mapping `Configuration`

```
using TestProg.DatabaseConverter.Entities.Sql;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace TestProg.DatabaseConverter.Mappings.Sql
{
    public class ConfigurationMap : ClassMap<Configuration>
    {
        public ConfigurationMap()
        {
            Table("Configuration");
            Id(x => x.Name).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
            Map(x => x.Value);
            Map(x => x.Description).Column("Desription");
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping `CompTool`

```
using TestProg.DatabaseConverter.Entities.Sql;
using FluentNHibernate.Mapping;

namespace TestProg.DatabaseConverter.Mappings.Sql
{
    public class CompToolMap: ClassMap<CompTool>
    {
        public CompToolMap()
        {
            Table("CompTools");
            Id(x => x.Id).Column("ID");
            Map(x => x.Name);
            Map(x => x.Description);
            Map(x => x.DefaultLocation);
            Map(x => x.DateModified);
            Map(x => x.OldId);
        }
    }
}
```

`Configuration` entity

```
using System;

namespace TestProg.DatabaseConverter.Entities.Sql
{
    public class Configuration
    {
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual string Value { get; set; }
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Code to create `Configuration` table:

```
CREATE TABLE Configuration
(
    Name nvarchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    Value nvarchar(50) DEFAULT '',
    Desription nvarchar(100) DEFAULT ''
)
```

Comment: Why are you moving data by code instead of SQL?

Comment: @Andre Because I decided in part to use this as an excercise to (re)familiarize with Fluent NHibernate and also there are some other 'issues' with the database that require a little more manipulation than just straight copying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `session.Save(...)` does not mean SQL `INSERT`.

The instance of NHibernate session represents a context / unit of work, which does *(or even hides)* the DB manipulation.

DB WRITE operations are done in batches, if needed or if we explicitly ask for. And the way how we can force WRITE operation si by calling

```
session.Flush();
```

Check these parts of documentation *(well all of them are helpful, but these cover session and its Flush mode)*

#### [2.3. Contextual Sessions](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/architecture.html#architecture-current-session)

and

#### [9.6. Flush](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-flushing)

> From time to time the ISession will execute the SQL statements needed to synchronize the ADO.NET connection's state with the state of objects held in memory.
>
> - from some invocations of `Find()` or `Enumerable()`
> - from `NHibernate.ITransaction.Commit()`
> - from `ISession.Flush()`

Comment: I'm aware save does not necessarily immediately insert to the DB but it does not ever insert.  I'm not just pausing it right after that call.  I've also tried flushing immediately after and still does not insert.

Comment: Session Flush (or transaction commit with FlushMode on commit) is the event, when INSERT will be issued. Save is just a way how to add instance into ISession session. After Flush, INSERT will always happen, or at least Exception will be thrown. So are you provide with some exception?

Comment: *sigh* I new it was something stupid, was by mistake calling flush on the access database session for this one and not the sql db.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Great to see that progress! Enjoy mighty NHibernate, sir ;)